# Minor bug found while reviewing a post

Tags: discussion, bug, review

This is a minor bug which I noticed while reviewing..

I accidentally pressed backspace when the review question poped up. I then pressed forward to go back to review question, and I **found that NEXT button now no longer functions**..
See image below

> [image]

***Notice there are duplicate question message appearing on screen which is uncommon.***

Then, I just did refresh and ISSUE seems to be resolved.. see image below..

> [image]

I did term this as **minor bug** because it in no way affected the site functionality or did stop me from reviewing(after refresh of-course..)

***Steps to reproduce bug***

- Go one screen back by clicking back or backspace button.
- then again go forward to the review question screen.
- Buttons dont work then.

Can we look to solve this...

Comment: In my case the NEXT button appeared b'coz it had already been reviewed, **I think** the same issue will be observed in normal case where SKIP, NO ACTION NEEDED buttons wont work..

Comment: Can you please provide us with your browser details?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. Version 27.0.1453.116 m