# Review buttons `Close' etc do not work with IE8 - workaround

Tags: discussion, review, internet-explorer

I reported this by email to team@stackexchange.com, and they referred me back here.

I am using IE8, which though no longer supported should, according to team@stackexchange.com still work wrt the review features, especially since a workaround works.

This is the workaround I am using: I click **Stats** then use the browser's **Back** to return to the page, and then I can click **Close**, **Leave Open**, etc. Refreshing the page is another workaround.

Seems like a bug.

Comment: Not a bug, since IE8 is not supported.

Comment: Specifically, see [the full list of supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/218097).

Comment: _I am using IE8_ why?

Comment: Because IE 6 stopped working, of course!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186643/221351 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152089/221351